# django queryset return single value

Tags: python, django

I have the following -

```
obj.owner_id = Owner.objects.filter(owner_name=owner_obj).values_list('owner_id')[0]
```

Problem is the value it's returning is a tuple.  Specifically this -

```
(786,)
```

All I want to return is the integer value or `786`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried doing `Owner.objects.filter(owner_name='Operations').values_list('owner_id')[0][0]`?

Comment: thanks that worked!  Get another error now I'll make another question for it.

Comment: Try this `Owner.objects.filter(owner_name='Operations').values_list('owner_id', flat=True)[0]`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For posterity, this also works and is (in my opinion) the cleanest option of all:

```
Owner.objects.values_list('owner_id', flat=True).get(owner_name=owner_obj)
```

Answer (score 9):

Assuming `owner_name` is unique, either of these will do the trick:

- `owner_id = Owner.objects.only('owner_id').get(owner_name=owner_name).owner_id`
- `owner_id = Owner.objects.values('owner_id').get(owner_name=owner_name)['owner_id']`
- `owner_id = Owner.objects.values_list('owner_id', flat=True).get(owner_name=owner_name)`

Documentation:

- [`only()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only)
- [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values)
- [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)